# How to autopopulate data from multiple sheets to one sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have multiple sheets which are renamed to sheets 1-5 with the very first sheet being called fruit salad.
In cell A1 of each numbered sheet there is a fruit

```
'1'A1=Apple
'2'A1=Banana
'3'A1=Kiwi
'4'A1=Pineapple
'5'A1=Grape
```

I would like the sheet named Fruit Salad to look like this

```
A1=**Fruit Salad**
A2=Apple
A3=Banana
A4=Kiwi
A5=Pineapple
A6=Grape
```

Is there a way to achieve this without manually typing up each sheet number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how much of your question is question and how much is background. 
Do you need help setting `A1` (to **`Fruit Salad`**),
or are you willing to just type that in?

You can do the rest with the `INDIRECT` function. 
You pass it a text string containing a cell address<sup>1</sup>
and it evaluates to the thing addressed by that string. 
So, enter

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet" & (ROW()-1) & "!A1")
```

into cell `A2` on the “Fruit Salad” sheet and drag/fill down. 
In cell `A2`, `ROW()` is 2, so `ROW()-1` is 1,
and the argument is `Sheet1!A1`, and so the function evaluates to `Apple`. 
Lower rows (with higher row numbers)
give you later sheets (with higher sheet numbers).
__________
<sup>1</sup> or a cell range address

Comment: Using a function to evaluate the position of the cell within my multiple sheets was what I was after. In my case, since my sheets were all renamed to just 1 and not Sheet1 I changed it to this. =INDIRECT((ROW()-1) & "!A1")